# Reading from .txt file into arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to read each of the 4 columns stored in a .txt file separated by a space into an array of their own. The text file may have hundreds of rows so reading until the end of file is desirable.

Example:

```
3.4407280e+003 6.0117545e+003 8.0132664e+002 2.5292922e+003
3.4163843e+003 5.9879421e+003 7.7792044e+002 2.5058547e+003
```

so typically it would be array 1 containing all the rows from the first and most left column and so on.

Comment: What datastructures do you want this to have? What have you gotten so far? How has it not worked?

Comment: You should specify whether there will ever be more than 4 numbers on a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) is your friend:

```
static const int MAX_FILE_ROWS = 200;

double lines[MAX_FILE_ROWS][4];
FILE *file = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FILE_ROWS; i++)
{
    if (feof(file))
        break;

    fscanf(file, "%lf %lf %lf %lf", &(lines[i][0]), &(lines[i][1]), &(lines[i][2]), &(lines[i][3]));
}

fclose(file);
```

Then, lines should contain the data you need.

Comment: ah thank you richard, to double check the approach how can i print this to screen. thanks

Comment: Don't forget to add a check for the number of elements read and set the value of lines[row][column] to some sentinel value, if you need to know whether or not the field existed.

Comment: @user1377485: You can include a printf (or fprintf(), as appropriate) immediately after the fscanf() line -- printf("%f %f %f %f\n", lines[i][0], lines[i][1], lines[i][2], lines[i][3]); -- Any errors are free puzzles ;)

Comment: Hey thanks julie for the print, its working fine now! i think i'll be making some tweaks! i will post again if im stuck :)) thanks everyone :))))

Comment: ah guys, its nearly perfect. but it stores the values with the decimal point four numbers into the value. for example: it should be: 3.4407280e+003 but it is stored as: 3440.7280e+003 this is true for all values.

Comment: @user1377485 `3.4407 * 10^3 = 3440.7`. Is this not what you want? if you are printing an extra `e+003`, than that is incorrect, fscanf automatically parses the `e+003` part of the number.

Comment: i see, thank you very much for your answers :). very impressed by the community on this site. thanks all